# Implement jQuery AutoComplete TextBox from database using AJAX PageMethods in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, asp.net, ajax

I work in ASP.NET c# and MySQL database.

I need to make the AutoComplete TextBox from database using AJAX and I have tried this tutorial on the web.

[Tutorial](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-jQuery-AutoComplete-TextBox-from-database-using-AJAX-PageMethods-in-ASPNet.aspx)

But I have a problem when the name consists of multiple words, e.g. :

> name: Plane

working on the search

> name: Planner of

not working because after **PostBack Page** the selected value on list in the **TextBox** is only *Planner* and the search return is empty.

If delete on **TextBox txtCp** the property

```
AutoPostBack="true"
```

and press **Enter** to search the script working.

Why ?

My code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCp" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtCp_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfCp" runat="server" />

[WebMethod]
public static string[] GetCustomers(string prefix)
{
    List<string> customers = new List<string>();

    using (OdbcConnection conn =
        new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM doName WHERE Name LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%'); ";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", prefix);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();

            using (OdbcDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    customers.Add(string.Format("{0}", sdr["Name"].ToString().ToUpper()));
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    return customers.ToArray();
}


protected void txtCp_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindData();
}


    $(function () {
        $("[id$=txtCp]").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("Default.aspx/GetCustomers") %>',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('-')[0],
                                val: item.split('-')[1]
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (e, i) {
                $("[id$=hfCp]").val(i.item.val);
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
```

Can you please help me figure out the problem?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT #1**

First passage :

[image]

Second passage :

[image]

Test code :

```
protected void txtCp_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomerId = hfCustomerId.Value;
    Text = txtSearch.Text;
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Name: " + CustomerId + "\\nID: " + Text + "');", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the discussion in the chat, I've reproduced the problem in IE11 emulating IE8. What happens is that when moving to the autocomplete selection list the browser interprets it as leaving the textbox and triggers a postback, which takes as value the incomplete prefix selection and reloads the whole page.

I believe that for your scenario, the solution is to use an UpdatePanel that contains the rest of the page and that updates when something changes in the textbox. This way, even if it fires a postback prematurely, the input element remains unchanged and you can trigger another one for the selected value.

Another solution would be to try to use another autocomplete solution, like [Select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#placeholders), maybe, which would work in all browsers consistently.

Anyway, I believe that in your scenario you will never need an incomplete value, you only need to select a customer or nothing. In that case a select with a filter rather than a text input with an autocomplete feels more natural, so try it even if you use an UpdatePanel as well.

Answer (score 0):

AutoPostback true means it does a postback when the value changes or you press Enter. If you want to use jQuery.Ajax, you should probably not use postbacks.

Comment: Thanks, and for postback ?

Comment: Do you press Enter when you want to choose your item from the autocomplete list? Maybe that's it: you cause a postback by pressing Enter when the value of the textbox is not yet updated. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639497/prevent-postback-on-enter-in-a-asp-net-inputfield

Comment: Thanks the problem is unsolved; please see **EDIT #1** in my first question.

Comment: Hi. Come join me in the chat and I will attempt to help you: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106713/implement-jquery-autocomplete-textbox-from-database-using-ajax-pagemethods-in-asp